# What should be considered when deciding on the order of input fields for a contact tracing form

Tags: forms, input-fields, information-architecture

I'm working on a contact tracing form for a travel booking website.

The following fields are required to be filled in by the user when they book their travel tickets.

- email
- address
- phone number

my question is, is there a specific order these input fields should be ordered in? or what should I consider in order to decide the order of them?

Comment: What are these fields used for? just collecting user data or something else relevant to the booking? I guess context will guide the priority of the fields.

Comment: email is required for the booking. others are required for contact tracing. that means if someone on the same flight had been detected positive for COVID. people on the same trip in nearby seats would be contacted for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider might be:

- which field has the most critical information (most of the time)
- how easy it is for the user to fill out the information
- how many entries for a particular field is possible (e.g. alternate address)
- which fields can be prefilled using existing data
- which fields require additional validation (and therefore needs checking)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific mandatory order for input fields.

you can create multiple groups of fields that are related, Give high priority to placing simple, mandatory, and crucial fields first

**First Group:** Should include personal information like name, and address.
**Second Group:** Add contact details starting with the most common field, email, and phone no.